# Line ending issue DOS > Linux > Java

Tags: java, linux, newline, dos

I'm having a bit of a trouble with a 160.000 lines file, this file was generated through an export from an xlsx file, it has a .txt extension but i'm afraid that it has been exported as DOS-like file,  at the end of each line it has the DOS line break.
I'm using a parser written in java, running on an Ubuntu environment, and i'm getting this when i run the parser (which i cannot edit because its part of a jar i cant access the source code), i get NumberFormatException where a number is expected, my line ends like this:

```
4449
```

But the parser sees it as

```
For input string: "4449&#xd;"<
```

Do you have a solution for this? again i cant access the parser myself, i will have to edit the file "on my Ubuntu machine" and remove those line ends.

Comment: What parser are you using? There may be an option to specify which line ending the file uses.

Comment: Sounds like something `sed` could do in about 10 seconds.

Comment: sed could not see that, thx for the advice anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `dos2unix` command on that file. That should fix the line terminators.

```
> dos2unix winfile.txt unixfile.txt
```

*Reference:*
[dos2unix man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Answer (score 0):

The parser is finding `&#xd;`, which is a windows carriage return; however, it is unable to parse these characters.  Go to the file and run a quick command `tr -d '\15\32' < winfile.txt > unixfile.txt`.

Reference:
http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html