# cant delete file using variable name in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to delete a file whose name is stored in a variable, but it doesn't  work. I'm getting

> A file or Directory in the path name does not exist

My code is

```
value=$(<try_text.txt)
rm -f /home/inform/output/$value
```

Comment: did you replace the `rm -f` with `echo` to see what the actual command looks like?

Comment: It's really not easy to help you if you don't share more Information. What **does** the actual command look like? Do you get the same error when you run it manually?

Comment: try_test.txt is in your working directory? As suggested by @bastian-j double-check the variable "value" gets the expected value. Share the output of "echo $value" and "ls -l /home/inform/output/$value"

Comment: share ls output please.

Comment: Trace your script using `set -x` to see what `$value` is being expanded to.  Quote your variable expansions, e.g. `/home/inform/output/"$value"`.  Post a [mcve] so that others can reproduce your symptoms and give full & accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

> when i tried deleting i got :
>
> ```
> cannot remove `/home/oracle/Omar2/B2BFiles/bm.txt\r': No such file or directory
> ```
>
> where does the \r come from ?

It comes from an editor which wrote the Windows line ending `\r\n` to `try_text.txt`. When reading that file, the Linux shell removed the Unix line ending `\n`, and the `\r` remained. To get rid of it, see e. g. the answers to the question [Line ending issue DOS > Linux > Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221720/line-ending-issue-dos-linux-java).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
value=try_text.txt
rm -f /home/inform/output/$value
```

Don't run the value variable in a subshell when it's not needed.

**EDIT**

Previously misunderstood the question, didn't see the '<'.

This works on my system:

```
value=$(</home/user/Documents/try_text.txt)
rm -f /home/user/Documents/$value
```

as @gile said, make sure the try_text.txt is in your working directory.

Comment: this does different thing from OP's attempt. The filename is saved in file, but what you are doing is, rm the file `try_text.txt`

Comment: Your suggestion would delete the file /home/inform/output/try_text.txt . It seems @omar-moghazi must delete the file name written inside try_text.txt

Comment: @SpaceCowboy the editing or your original answer changed it so last comments from Kent and me don't make sense anymore.

Comment: when i tried deleting i got : cannot remove `/home/oracle/Omar2/B2BFiles/bm.txt\r': No such file or directory where does the \r come from ?